# Is there a specific way for introducing a 'setText()' JTextArea method when using the NetBeans GUI Builder?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jscrollpane, jtextarea

As a school project I've been asked to make a simple text-based RPG in an object-oriented manner and using a GUI. I recently discovered that the NetBeans IDE 12.1 features a helpful GUI builder, which helped me generate the basic JFrame and layout.

The window has a JScrollPane enabled JTextArea, a JTextField and two additional JTextAreas. The code looks like as follows:

```
    /**
     * Creates new form GUI
     */
    public BackupGUI() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        scrollPrompt = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        storyPrompt = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        commandLine = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        nullScrollPane = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        enemyInfo = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        nullScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        playerInfo = new javax.swing.JTextArea();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
        setUndecorated(true);

        scrollPrompt.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(51, 51, 51));
        scrollPrompt.setBorder(null);
        scrollPrompt.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        scrollPrompt.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scrollPrompt.setViewportBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0)));
        scrollPrompt.setAutoscrolls(true);

        storyPrompt.setEditable(false);
        storyPrompt.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(51, 51, 51));
        storyPrompt.setColumns(20);
        storyPrompt.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
        storyPrompt.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(153, 153, 153));
        storyPrompt.setLineWrap(true);
        storyPrompt.setRows(5);
        storyPrompt.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        storyPrompt.setBorder(null);
        storyPrompt.setCaretColor(new java.awt.Color(102, 102, 102));
        storyPrompt.setSelectedTextColor(new java.awt.Color(51, 51, 51));
        storyPrompt.setSelectionColor(new java.awt.Color(153, 153, 153));
        scrollPrompt.setViewportView(storyPrompt);

        commandLine.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(72, 72, 72));
        commandLine.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Yu Gothic UI Light", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        commandLine.setText(">>> ");
        commandLine.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0)));
        commandLine.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                commandLineActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        commandLine.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                commandLineKeyPressed(evt);
            }
        });

        nullScrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        nullScrollPane.setToolTipText("");
        nullScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

        enemyInfo.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(102, 102, 102));
        enemyInfo.setColumns(20);
        enemyInfo.setLineWrap(true);
        enemyInfo.setRows(5);
        enemyInfo.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        enemyInfo.setSelectedTextColor(new java.awt.Color(60, 60, 60));
        enemyInfo.setSelectionColor(new java.awt.Color(204, 204, 204));
        nullScrollPane.setViewportView(enemyInfo);

        nullScrollPane1.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        nullScrollPane1.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

        playerInfo.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(102, 102, 102));
        playerInfo.setColumns(20);
        playerInfo.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Segoe UI", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        playerInfo.setLineWrap(true);
        playerInfo.setRows(5);
        playerInfo.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        playerInfo.setSelectedTextColor(new java.awt.Color(60, 60, 60));
        playerInfo.setSelectionColor(new java.awt.Color(204, 204, 204));
        nullScrollPane1.setViewportView(playerInfo);

        scrollPrompt.getVerticalScrollBar().setBackground(java.awt.Color.BLACK);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(commandLine, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 700, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(scrollPrompt))
                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(nullScrollPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 260, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(nullScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(scrollPrompt, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 500, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(0, 0, 0)
                .addComponent(commandLine))
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(nullScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 270, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(nullScrollPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 270, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
        );

        setSize(new java.awt.Dimension(960, 540));
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void commandLineActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                           

    private void commandLineKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                       
        if (evt.getKeyCode() == java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE){
            String s = commandLine.getText();
            if (s.equals(">>> ")){
                evt.consume();
            }
        }
        if (!commandLine.getText().startsWith(">>> ")){
            commandLine.setText(">>>");
        }
    }                                      

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */

    public void create(){
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Windows".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(BackupGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(BackupGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(BackupGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(BackupGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new BackupGUI().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JTextField commandLine;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea enemyInfo;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane nullScrollPane;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane nullScrollPane1;
    public void setPlayerText(String t){
        playerInfo.setText(t);
        playerInfo.requestFocusInWindow();
    }
    private javax.swing.JTextArea playerInfo;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane scrollPrompt;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea storyPrompt;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Within this code I tried to include a method with the functionality to change the text of one of the text areas whilst the program is running, however when I built and ran the program said functionality appeared not to work.

I was wondering if this is a fault on my part, or just a trait of the NetBeans GUI builder.

Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: `"Within this code I tried to include a method with the functionality to change the text of one of the text areas whilst the program is running"` - Where in your code did you try to do this? I can't see it.

Comment: ```java                                                            public void setPlayerText(String t){
        playerInfo.setText(t);
        playerInfo.requestFocusInWindow();                                          }                                                                             ```

Comment: *a helpful GUI builder...* If the GUI builder is so helpful, why are you here asking a question?  When you're ready to learn Java Swing, the Oracle tutorial [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) will be there to teach you.  Skip the NetBeans section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, you've created the method to change the text within the `playerInfo` JTextArea but nowhere in your code do you call this method to actually make a text change. You can call this method after your JTextArea is initialized, for example:

```
setPlayerText("I want this text in my PlayerInfo JTextArea!");
```

I would suspect you want to do this from your **commandLineActionPerformed** method that is called from the commandLine actionPerformed event which is fired one the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key is hit. In this case you might have something like this:

```
private void commandLineActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
    // Make sure something is provided within the Command 
    // Line JTextField, if not get outta here!.
    if (commandLine.getText().trim().isEmpty() || commandLine.getText().trim().equals(">>>")) {
        return;
    } 
    
    // Place NEW (overwrite) text within the playerInfo JTextArea.
    // To 'append' text you would need to do something different.
    setPlayerText(commandLine.getText().substring(3));
}
```

Comment: In a different file I was calling a new object and calling the setPlayerInfo method. Will this still work if the method call is in a different class.

Comment: Since the setPlayerInfo() method is public you should be able to, for example: `BackupGUI.setPlayerInfo("Blah blah blah");`.